# Getting image and its title

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api

Hello i am new to jquery, ive an api from which i need to get the image and display its name in the same div
[i am getting it like this i want the bike image and name in same div (like this http://www.metrobikes.in/booking/choose-models?start_date=24+Oct+2017&start_time=16%3A00&end_date=25+Oct+2017&end_time=13%3A00&city_id=1&_token=et3dhAZdro5jCyGeD2z6oHUi4BvMZwI15gBVgHiY)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzueR.png)

run "chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security"

### to get the result

```js
///////////////////////////////ASDF///////////////////////////////////
$("#btnAjaxCall").click(function(){
    fetchDataAndDisplay();
});





$('#selet-city').on('change', function() {
    fetchDataAndDisplay($('#selet-city option:selected').val());
});

function fetchDataAndDisplay(id){
    $.ajax({
        url:'http://metrobikes.in/api/cities/'+id+'/models',
        /*url:"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts",*/
        method:"GET"
    }).done(function(data){
        for (var i=0; i<data.result.data.length; i++){
            console.log(data.result.data[i].image.full);

            $(".col-xs-8").append('<div class="selected-bike-s1">' + data.result.data[i].name + '<div/>');




            $(".bb-img .bike-imgs").append('<img style="width: 100%;" src="'+data.result.data[i].image.full+'" />');



            /*$("#image_from_url").prepend('<div class="selected-bike-s1">' + data.result.data[i].name + '<div/>')*/




        };


    });
};
```

```css
.date-time-wrap{margin-top: 10px;}
        .selected-bike{font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 16px;}
        .selected-bike-s1{font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 16px; }
        .bike-price-s1{font-size: 12px; color:grey;}
        .wrap-s1{margin-top: 10px;}
        .wrap-s1 img{margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px;}
        .min-bill-s2{font-size: 12px; color:grey;}
        .s2-book-btn{    background: black;
            text-align: center;
            color: #ffffff;
            font-size: 28px;
            font-weight: bold;
            margin-top: 15px;
            width: 100%;
            display: block;
        }


        .proceed-s4{    float: right;
            background: black;
            color: #ffffff;
            font-size: 16px;
            font-weight: bold;
            padding: 11px 26px;}
        .booked-bike-s4{font-size: 12px; color:grey;}
        .booked-bike-price-s4{font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold;}
        .book-btn-wrap{background: #bbbbbb;
            padding: 25px 15px;margin-top: 10px;}
        .back-slide{    font-size: 24px;}
        .bike-brand{font-weight: bold; font-size: 12px; text-align: center;margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 15px;}
        .con-add-cmnts{margin-top: 10px;}
        .con-wallet-wrap{margin-bottom: 10px;}
        .promo-apply-btn{background: black;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
            border-radius: 10px;
            /* overflow: hidden; */
            padding: 4px 10px;}
        .confirm-bike-price{margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;}
        .con-location{ margin-bottom: 10px;}
        .con-name-price-wrap{margin-bottom: 10px;}
        .if-city-select{margin-bottom: 10px;}
        .p3form{margin-top: 15px;}
        .back-summary{    font-size: 22px;
            margin-top: 20px;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/jquery.datetimepicker.css"/>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/jquery.datetimepicker.full.js"></script>


    <style>
        
    </style>

</head>
<body>

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <!-- <ol class="carousel-indicators">
         <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
         <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
         <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
     </ol>-->

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">

            <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 date-time-wrap">
                <input type="button" id="btnAjaxCall" value="Ajax Call" />
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 if-city-select">
                        <select class="form-control" id="selet-city" >
                            <option selected disabled>Please select a City</option>
                            <option vlaue="city-1">1</option>
                            <option>2</option>
                            <option>3</option>
                            <option>4</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Start date and time" value="" class="form-control" id="startdatetimepicker"/>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="End date and time" value="" class="form-control" id="enddatetimepicker"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>




            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 wrap-s1" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1">







                <div class="row">
                    <div class="bb-img" id="image_from_url">

                        <div class="bike-imgs">

                        </div>

                        <div class="qwer col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
                            <div class="selected-bike-s1">Dio</div>
                            <div class="bike-price-s1">Bike price</div>
                        </div>


                    </div>





                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 bike-price-s1">
                        jaynagr
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 bike-price-s1">
                        MINIMUM BILLIN
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">


                <div class="back-slide" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span> </div>
                <img src="http://www.metrobikes.in/img/bikes_upload/thumbnail/Honda-Dio-10.png" class="img-responsive">
                <div class="bike-brand">
                    HONDA
                </div>

                <div class="selected-bike text-center">
                    Dio
                </div>
                <form>
                    <div class="form-group">

                        <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
                            <option selected disabled>Please select an area</option>
                            <option>1</option>
                            <option>2</option>
                            <option>3</option>
                            <option>4</option>
                        </select>

                    </div>
                </form>

                <div class="min-bill-s2">
                    Minimum billing of 1 hour on weedays and 24 hours on weekends
                </div>


                <div class="min-bill-s2">
                    Rs <span>40</span>/hour and <span>750</span>/day
                </div>


                <a href="#" class="s2-book-btn" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2">
                    Book Now
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">


                <h4 class="text-center" >  <span class="res-back pull-left glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></span>
                    <span style="margin-right: 5%;">Reserve your </span> </h4>
                <h3 class="text-center"> <span>Dio</span> TODAY</h3>
                <form class="p3form">
                    <div class="form-group ">

                        <div class="col-12">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Name">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group ">

                        <div class="col-12">
                            <input class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="Email">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group ">

                        <div class="col-12">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Phome number">
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <div class="row">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Start date and time" value="" class="p3-time form-control" id="startdatetimepickerp3" style="    width: 97%;"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <div class="row">
                            <input  type="text" placeholder="End date and time" value="" class="p3-time form-control" id="enddatetimepickerp3"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

                <!--   <div class="row">
                       <div class="col-md-6">
                           <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First name">
                       </div>
                       <div class="col-md-6">
                           <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last name">
                       </div>
                   </div>-->

            </div>

            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 book-btn-wrap">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="booked-bike-s4">
                            Dio
                        </div>

                        <div class="booked-bike-price-s4">
                            Rs.400/-
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                    <div class="row">
                        <a class="proceed-s4" href="#" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"> PROCEED</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <p>TERMS AND CONDITIONS</p>
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 book-btn-wrap">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="booked-bike-s4">
                            Dio
                        </div>

                        <div class="booked-bike-price-s4">
                            Rs.400/-
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                    <div class="row">
                        <a class="proceed-s4" href="#" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="4"> BOOK NOW</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="item">

            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                        <span class="back-summary glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-10">
                        <h2 class="text-center"> SUMMARY </h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <img src="http://www.metrobikes.in/img/bikes_upload/thumbnail/Honda-Dio-10.png" class="img-responsive">

            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 con-name-price-wrap">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 confirm-bike-name">

                        DIO

                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6 cl-xs-6 text-right sconfirm-bike-price">

                        Rs 400/-

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 con-location">
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 con-label">
                        <strong>FROM</strong>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 con-from" >
                        <div class="row">
                            FROM DATE AND TIME
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 con-to">
                        <strong>TO</strong>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 con-to" >
                        TO DATE AND TIME
                    </div>

                </div>


            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 con-pick-location">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 con-pikloc-title">
                        <strong>PICK UP LOCATION</strong>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-8 con-pikloc-loc">
                        Location
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 con-promo-wrap">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                        <h4>PROMO CODE</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-9">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter promo code">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <div class="promo-apply-btn">
                            Apply
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12">

                <h4>BALANCE</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 con-wallet-wrap">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-9">
                        AVAILAL AMOUNT
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        6
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 con-redeem-amt-wrap">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-9">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter redeem amount here">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3 ">
                        <div class="promo-apply-btn">
                            Redeem
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 con-add-cmnts">

                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Additional comments">

            </div>

            <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 con-chk">

                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label><input type="checkbox" value="">I am over 18</label>
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label><input type="checkbox" value="">I have a valid driving license and required documents</label>
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label><input type="checkbox" value="">I agree to <a data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"> terms and conditions </a></label>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 book-btn-wrap">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="booked-bike-s4">
                            Dio
                        </div>

                        <div class="booked-bike-price-s4">
                            Rs.400/-
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                    <div class="row">
                        <a class="proceed-s4" href="#" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"> CONFIRM </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>



</div>


</div>

<script src="js/jquery.datetimepicker.js"></script>
<script src="js/iframe/frame.js"></script>






</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can not help you. But I can tell you this.. If you want users to understand you and you want them to fill out your form, tell them how to write down date and time instead of saying start date and time

Comment: i just want to get the image n display it

Comment: I said... I can not help you. I just thought I would tell you that your form is unclear and users would not understand it enough to be filling it out

Answer (score 0):

In console, you take error "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

Example code with PHP:

```
// jQuery part
function get_data_bike(id){
  $.ajax({
    url: "get_data.php",
    data:{id:id}
  }).done(function(data) {
    // parse data with JSON.parse( data )
  });
}

// PHP part, file get_data
<?php
$url = "http://metrobikes.in/api/cities/".$_GET['id']."/models";
echo file_get_contents($url);
die();
?>
```

Comment: cant i do it by just using jquery?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin

on the server is metrobikes.in, must be allowed access for your query, from your domain